# Stop whole multi-display scrolling?

Tags: upgrade, multiple-monitors, display, 20.04

I just upgraded 19.10 to 20.04.  I have two monitors, one landscape (secondary) to the right of another, portrait (primary).  It appears that my screen workspace is now wider than my monitors.  When I move the mouse off of the right of the right display, both displays scroll (all windows, dock, top bar, etc) and I can now see the right end of the top bar (power, volume, etc).  The reverse happens when I move the mouse off the left of the left display.  In terms of computer graphics, my displays seem to be acting somewhat like a viewport into a larger world space.

How can I switch back so that my total "display space" matches my "world space"?

Part of the left display's background image is on the right display.
I can't move windows past a point near the middle of the left display, but I can move them all the way to the right (scrolling the right display).

Software & Updates, Additional Drivers, indicates that I am using NVIDIA GP107GL [Quadro Pro P1000], with the recommended NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-440 (proprietary, tested).  I tried the -435 driver, but got install errors.

Edit:
More info.  I've found that if I swap the positions of my monitors (portait on left, landscape on right), the problem goes away.  Moving them back makes the problem return.  This is acting more like a bug than a settings issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recent updates have fixed the problem, so I conclude it was a bug that has now been fixed.